# Use python 2.7 for some apps, while keeping python 2.6 for the OS (linux fedora/centos)

Tags: python, linux, centos, fedora, meld

How can I use python 2.7 for some apps, while keeping python 2.6 for the OS?

I am using CentOS6.6 (based on RHEL 6 / Fedora 12), and would like to install some recent packages such as meld 3.13, latest rabbitcvs, etc...
It requires python 2.6 to run.

when I try to run meld 3.13, it says "Meld requires Python 2.7 or higher."

I have successively installed python 2.7 following this tutorial
http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

how can I tell meld to use python2.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to install python 2.7 on CentOS 6 for some apps only without touching the default system provided python 2.6 is to use [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/).

Check page of [software collection `python27`](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/), it provides description how to install it and link to the package.

It works like this: the collection installs packages into separate directory tree in `/opt/rh/python27` and doesn't have any effect until [it is enabled](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-Enabling_the_Software_Collection).

In your case you can create wrapper script which will run your version of meld with `python27` collection. For example save following script into `~/bin/meld`:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="/path/to/your/meld $@"
scl enable python27 "$COMMAND"
```

Then every time you run meld command, it would be executed by python2.7 (assuming your meld is not already available in your `PATH`).

See more details in [Packaging Wrappers for Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-Packaging_Wrappers_for_Software_Collections) (while you are not packaging anything, the tip with wrapper seems to be useful in your case).

Comment: thanks! so if I want for example meld to always use python 2.7, how would I do that?
I found the following command:
scl action software_collection_1 software_collection_2 command
would it be:
scl meld python27 meld

Comment: I have added an example how to create wrapper which would run meld with python 2.7. It may not be 100% correct as I don't have access to any machine where I could install that software collection right now, but you should get the basic idea here.

Answer (score 1):

virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

For example:

```
$ python --version  # 2.7.6
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 myenv  # assign python version
$ . myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ python --version  # 3.4.3
```

Now you can use python 3.4 in the virtual environment.

To quit:

```
$ deactivate
```